# Laravel permissions Ubuntu VPS - Dig. Ocean -Runs but Can't create directory error, OR if w/o changed permissions it's a monolog unable open fs 500 er

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, nginx, permissions

Please please help me. I'm miserable right now from all the back and forth attempts to fix this great project that ran great locally on myusername staff   (user/group) setup. I'm a little confused in laravel about the user/group needed as git is was pulls the code in and I tried to directly SFTP it and it still claimed it root root.

My root looks like a normal laravel project which happily runs but when I go to open a photo in my CMS i spent time doing to save time and help repeat redundancy with a Laravel project CMS and components I can build add in the routes and go but now that i'm wanting to go live in production i have issues since i'm working with this VPS. (Laravel version is latest or semi-recent version) and php-4.3

/storage and /bootstrap directories were owned by root then changed to www-data, all directories but storage are owned by myuser   (lets call it **myuser** , nginx's **www-data** , ubuntu's **root**   I unfortunately clone the git repository before I fully setup the droplet up. I know root can cause issues or something for projects to just go smoother but with some danger. ALL else functions okay to my knowledge. I just dont get it and i'm happy to post more code and stacks, trees, etc. Anything to help me unscrew this thing is so very appreciated.

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File::getTargetFile
vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php:109


Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException
Unable to create the "projectname/adminpanel/assets/img/profile/" directory.
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File::getTargetFile
vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php:109



            throw new FileException(sprintf('Could not move the file "%s" to "%s" (%s).', $this->getPathname(), $target, strip_tags($error)));

        }


        @chmod($target, 0666 & ~umask());


        return $target;

    }


    /**

     * @return self

     */

    protected function getTargetFile($directory, $name = null)

    {

        if (!is_dir($directory)) {

            if (false === @mkdir($directory, 0777, true) && !is_dir($directory)) {

                throw new FileException(sprintf('Unable to create the "%s" directory.', $directory));

            }

        } elseif (!is_writable($directory)) {

            throw new FileException(sprintf('Unable to write in the "%s" directory.', $directory));

        }

 

        $target = rtrim($directory, '/\\').\DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.(null === $name ? $this->getBasename() : $this->getName($name));

 

        return new self($target, false);

    }

 

    /**

     * Returns locale independent base name of the given path.

     *
```

Now i'm getting this
and php artisan storage:link run as user throws me

```
 UnexpectedValueException  : The stream or file "/var/www/personal/storage/logs/laravel-2021-03-31.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

  at /var/www/personal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:111
    107|             restore_error_handler();
    108|             if (!is_resource($this->stream)) {
    109|                 $this->stream = null;
    110| 
  > 111|                 throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('The stream or file "%s" could not be opened: '.$this->errorMessage, $this->url));
    112|             }
    113|         }
    114| 
    115|         if ($this->useLocking) {

  Exception trace:

  1   Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler::write()
      /var/www/personal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php:121

  2   Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler::write()
      /var/www/personal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php:42

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

from earlier, an error I originally dealt with. I've now gone completely full circle, I was getting this and a 500 error but at least I can use the app, it looks fine, but something's totally wrong simple or a complication of things maybe if someone can help solve this new error we can id the real problem which may not have anything to do with what I was thinking, for all I know I just needed to start nginx all over again after sites-enabled changes and ubuntu setup changes, (perhaps a /bootstrap and a /storage dir change ownership to www-data then restarted and then ran without 500 errors a monolog error since and i've been using it and the database to add content, I just can't add img content which process has laravel create a related directory and file based on respective location in this case it's on the adminpanel side in profile settings so naturally the error was long a i.e ../../adminpanel/../../profile/ **speaking on uploading 128x128 px avatar in a section profile / directory and name is something also I think). I think I included it in the question however now i'm back and worried about `Unable to open file stream` the **new error** below. What information would be most useful to troubleshoot this again.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Laravel will use `www-data` user to do anything... so if you **own** `storage` folder, then Laravel will not be able to write logs to `/var/www/personal/storage/logs`, so you should **only own** the folder you want created inside `/var/www/personal/storage/app/public` (if you must own the folder).

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `public` disk uses the `local` driver and stores its files in `storage/app/public`. So, I'm assuming that's where your images are stored.

To make these files accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`, which you can do by simply running:

```sh
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: yes so i've run the basic storage:link and many others custom and rarer ones too. (Linux Nginx, u+g, git) I am what I thought was fairly-very knowledgeable about these laravel environments,  projects running and being serves to my domain and everything operates fast. When logged into my app which has an adminpanel portion w/ some CMS styling placeholders widgets and page sections-frontend. Looks alot like Wp dash or Elementor, or Adobe AEM+CQ5 sort of cms thing but laravel. Site's up, built, content is currently pop'd and database is connected, it saves text, and other data. it wont make dirs.